# Sending parameters in ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to post some data to a web method, But every time it is showing error as: **"Invalid JSON primitive: CityId. "**

For simplicity i have defined all my ajax post , get as below:

```
function ajaxPost(url, type, param, fetchAsync) {

    return $.ajax({ type: type, data: param,
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: fetchAsync
    });
}
var ajax = {
    Post: function (url, param, fetchType) {
        return ajaxPost(url, "POST", param, fetchType);
    },
    Get: function (url, param, fetchType) {
        return ajaxPost(url, "GET", param, fetchType);
    }
};
```

And i am posting to a method like:

```
                  var CityId1 = dataRecord.CityId;


                       ajax.Post("AddCities.aspx/DeleteCity", { CityId: CityId1 }, false).success(function (data) {
                        if (data.d[0] > 1)
                                 {
                                   logger.error(data.d[1]);
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
                                 }
```

Every time it is showing error as i mentioned above...!!!!!
Where am i mistaking???

and the signature of my webmethod:

```
                   [WebMethod]
                   public static string[] DeleteCity(int CityId)
                   {

                   }
```

**Update:**

```
                $.ajax({
                             type: 'POST',
                             data: "{'CityId':'" + CityId1 + "'}",
                             url: location.pathname + "/DeleteCity",
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                             dataType: "json",
                             async: true,
                             success: function (data) {

                              if (data.d[0] > 1) {

                                        logger.error(data.d[1]);
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .

                            });
```

If i post like this it is working for meee

Answer (score 0):

I am getting data property using below code. You can try $j.parseJSON(data); method

```
$j.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: URL,
            data: "{}",
            type: "GET",
            async: async,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("GetData - " + error);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var objData = $j.parseJSON(data);
            },
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
```

Comment: Actually i want make use of the simplified ajax post which i defined in above!! If i normally post the method like u did, that is working fine for me also